# NSWindow closing and controlling issues in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nswindow

I met the issues of NSWindow regarding closing it when the application starts. There are plenty of examples, however, I can not get the proper effect, perhaps I missing something.

Firstly, in many examples there is the recommendation to use "[self window]" but I get the error like "No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'window'".

Then I use the round way: "[[self view] window]". Anyway, the window is not closed after the execution of the code:

```
NSWindow *win = [[self view] window];
[win performClose:self];
```

or

```
NSWindow *win = [[self view] window];
[win close];
```

The next one also does not give any results as I expect, according to the documentation:

```
[win orderOut:self];
```

The code compiles but I can see the window. Of course, I tried:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [win.windowController windowShouldClose:self] ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
```

It outputs "NO", so, it means that the window, which appear when I run my application, cannot be closed? Is there any way how to work around it? Why I cannot control that main window following the way the documentation suggests?

I checked for the import "#import AppKit/AppKit.h;" as well.

Answer (score 1):

All of this suggests that `win` is `nil`. The view of your view controller is not in a window.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I checked it. So, where is it if not in a window. I want to access, and close the window which appears when the app is started?

Comment: Views can exist outside of any window. They just can't be shown until they are added to a window. What code created the window which appears when the app started? If it's from the main NIB, then there's probably an outlet connected to it, perhaps from the app delegate. If you have a window controller, then that has a `window` property which refers to the window. If you created the window in code, then you should have stored a strong reference to the window in some property of yours.

Comment: I think you can move that comprehensive comment into the answer. It is a standard cocoa application. I guess it is in MainStoryboard. Yes, I see that there is an outlet between the options in XCode. How to control that outlet connected to the main window with the code? Still going back to the main question how to close the window programmatically from any method?